# exim and clear invalid e-mails

Tags: exim, queue

I have an exim queue now of over 1000 e-mails and I want to run the queue and delete all the e-mails that are going to invalid e-mails(ones that no longer exist)

Answer (score 3):

```
exiqgrep -i -f [luser]@domain | xargs exim -Mrm
```

Answer (score 2):

If the messages are in the queue and frozen, the below SHOULD work -- however I have not tested it and take no responsibility if it instead becomes sentient and eats your mailserver

```
for i in `mailq | grep "\*\*\* frozen \*\*\*" | cut -f 3 -d " "` ; do exim -Mrm $i ; done
```

Change the grep pattern as required if you need to hit non-frozen messages (this is easiest if you can be confident you can nuke *everything* in the queue, and be sure to run as a user who can run exim -Mrm and mailq usefully -- you may need to insert `sudo` before `mailq` and `exim -Mrm`...

Also, there is almost certainly a cleaner way to do this using xargs rather than the `for` built-in and backticks. Hopefully someone will be along shortly with that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Scan the files in `/var/spool/exim4/msglog` for the invalid addresses.

You can mark an address as delivered with a command like (use the invalid address)
 `cd /var/spool/exim4/msglog; for msg in $(grep -l address); do exim4 -Mmd $msg address`.

You can clear the messages with the command `cd /var/spool/exim4/msglog; exim4 -M *`.  This will try to deliver all messages in the queue.

You can block incoming messages to old addresses using an alias in `/etc/aliases` like:

`address : :fail: No longer here`

See `man exim4` and `man aliases` for more information.